# Скрыть папку из url htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Есть ссылка: site.ru/shop

Как сделать, чтобы при открытии **site.ru** показывалась страница **site.ru/shop,**
но в URL не отображалось **/shop**.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо так в .htaccess в корне сайта сделать надо:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /shop [QSA,L]
```

Регулярка `^$` должна среагировать на url вида `ваш_сайт.ru` или `ваш_сайт.ru/`. А вот вместо `/shop` видимо следует подставить вызов реального файла, который запускается при url `ваш_сайт.ru/shop`